# Cant create project using the ng new command

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to create an Angular project using the command

```
ng new my
```

The creation starts but the get stuck at some point and never ends. I get the following terminal outputs,

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
installing ng2
  create .editorconfig
  create README.md
  create src/app/app.component.css
  create src/app/app.component.html
  create src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  create src/app/app.component.ts
  create src/app/app.module.ts
  create src/app/index.ts
  create src/app/shared/index.ts
  create src/assets/.gitkeep
  create src/assets/.npmignore
  create src/environments/environment.prod.ts
  create src/environments/environment.ts
  create src/favicon.ico
  create src/index.html
  create src/main.ts
  create src/polyfills.ts
  create src/styles.css
  create src/test.ts
  create src/tsconfig.json
  create src/typings.d.ts
  create angular-cli.json
  create e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts
  create e2e/app.po.ts
  create e2e/tsconfig.json
  create .gitignore
  create karma.conf.js
  create package.json
  create protractor.conf.js
  create tslint.json
Successfully initialized git.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
```

After the last line, it stops forever and I quit after providing 10 minutes of time. Though the files are generated properly and when I run `ng server` I get the  errors,

```
1st time: it count find the portfinder 
2nd time:  module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/cli'
```

I assume I need to provide more time to `Installing packages for tooling` or is there something else. This is the first time I use `Angular` and hence, slightly confused about the issue. Thanks.

```
EDIT:
```

I again tried and waits long enough to get the following error message,

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Chaklader/Desktop/my/npm-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO TO RESOLVE THE ISSUE?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the next steps and solve your problem:

1. In old version of `angular-cli` you just use
   ng new App --skip-npm to avoid install. For latest version you can use ng `new App --skip-install` instead;
2. Get into the directory use `cd App`and and then installed npm via `npm install`.
3. Wait for minutes to let the installation to complete. With using `CLI`, here is how to compile and run it `ng serve`.

I solved the problem with reference to this [solution-angular-ng-new-command-stuck-at-installing-packages-for-tooling-via-npm](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3032%20http://www.fahdmurtaza.com/solution-angular-ng-new-command-stuck-at-installing-packages-for-tooling-via-npm/).